# CSS issue in CS Cart website

Tags: html, css, z-index

This is my first question in stackoverflow, so I will be quick and precise.

I am dealing with a css/z-index related problem in a website. The url of the site is  http://birthz.com and the problem is that the slideshow overlaps the submenus of the top menu. If you hover for example over "Skin care" there is a submenu that show up, but gets hidden by the slides of the slideshow.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I tried increasing the z-index of the submenu's ul element but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: You should try to include the relevant HTML/CSS inside the question. Without that, this question has no value for future readers.

Comment: Ok I will see what I can do. Although it's a bit complicated. Thank you for the suggestion I will try to update the question.

Comment: It's probably not worth doing it for this question. Do it for future questions though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this

```
div.MagicToolboxContainer {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 0;
}
```